# How to custom sort this data in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have some hard time figuring it out how to custom sort data below the way I want to. Meaning it should be in order like this:

```
201-1-1
201-1-2
201-1-3
.......
201-2-1
```

and so on if you know what I mean.

Instead I'm getting this sort executing below code:

```
select * 
from test.dbo.accounts 
order by account_name asc
```

Output:

```
201-10-1
201-10-2
201-1-1
201-11-1
201-11-2
201-11-3
201-11-4
201-11-6
201-1-2
201-12-1
201-12-2
201-12-3
201-12-4
201-12-6
201-1-3
201-13-1
201-13-2
201-13-3
201-13-4
201-13-6
201-1-4
201-14-1
201-14-2
201-14-4
201-14-6
201-15-1
201-15-2
201-15-3
201-15-4
201-15-6
201-1-6
201-16-1
201-16-2
201-16-3
201-16-4
201-16-6
201-16-7
201-1-7
201-17-1
201-17-2
201-17-4
201-17-6
201-18-1
201-18-2
201-18-3
201-18-4
201-18-6
201-19-1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. String manipulation in SQL can be extremely cumbersome. There might be a better way to do this, but this does seem to work.

```
select accoutn_name
from test.dbo.accounts
order by left(account_name,charindex('-',account_name,1)-1)
                        ,replace(right(left(account_name,CHARINDEX('-',account_name,1)+2),2),'-', '')
                        ,REPLACE(right(account_name,2),'-','')
```

BTW, this is a very expensive process to run. If it's productionalized, you'll want to come up with a better solution.

[image]

Comment: sorry, actually your solution was proper. I didn't notice at first that the other one did not group properly.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

For your sample data, this following trick will work:

```
order by len(account_name), account_name
```

This only works because the only variable length component is the second component and because the hyphen is "smaller" than digits.

You should normalize the accounts names so all the components are the same length, by left padding the numbers with zeros.